# Web view not rendering page after onPageFinish() called Showing blank page for some time and renders the page? - Android

Tags: android, node.js

I am loading dymanic webpage from my server designed in JQuery and NodeJS inside webview. I kept loading bar inside WebClient onPageStarted() and removed the same in onPageFinished().

But after calling page finish still web page is not rendered and webview showing blank page for some time and then renders the page after few seconds.

The same is working properly with other sites like google, etc.

Is there a way we designed the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(WebPage.this, "",
                "Loading...", true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(yourURL);
    }
```